# Rails: What is the correct Association for these models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, has-and-belongs-to-many, polymorphic-associations

What is the correct association for this problem?

There are three models:

- Residents
- Parties
- Addresses

Each `Resident` and `Party` has an `Address`

Each `Address` can belong to a `Resident` or `Party` or to both.

There can be multiple `Parties` at the same `Address` and multiple `Residents` living at that location.

Is a **habtm** relationship the best solution for these models?

I looked into doing **polymorphic associations** but a conflict arises because an `Address` might belong to both `Resident`  and to `Party` mulitple times

---

I would like to be able to do things like...

```
address = Address.find_or_create_by_street("100 Some Street")

# Associate the Party with a specific Address:
party_object.address = address

# Find all Parties happening at a specific Address:
address.parties do ...

# Find all Residents located at a specific Address:
address.residents.each do ...
```

---

Running Rails 3 + MySQL 5.5

Comment: the polymorphic is exactly what you need. Post your code, it would just need some debug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see a need for Polymorphism

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :parties
  has_many :residents
end

class Party < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :address
end

class Resident < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :address
end

 # Address can have multiple parties, and multiple residents. 
 # Resident belongs to an address (lives at only 1 address). 
 # A party belongs to an address (party can be only at 1 address).

address = Address.create(:name => "10 something street.")
address.parties << Party.create(:name => "first")
address.parties << Party.create(:name => "second")
address.residents << Resident.create(:name => "John")
address.residents << Resident.create(:name => "Jane")


Party.first.address.name #10 something street.
Resident.first.address.name #10 something street.
address.parties.size #2
address.residents.size #2

Resident.first.address.parties.size #2
```

Answer (score 1):

The Rails gurus seem to be phasing out their use of habtm. I think you can do it with a straightforward has_many:

```
class Resident < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :address
end

class Party < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :address
end

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :residents 
  has_many :parties
end
```

From those associations you can do things like

```
party.address
address.residents
address.parties
party.address.residents
resident.address.parties
```

**Schema**

The SQL schema (leaving out the Rails defaults) that would go with this would look something like:

```
create_table "residents" do |t|
  t.integer  "address_id"
  t.string   "name"
  ... etc
end

create_table "parties" do |t|
  t.integer  "address_id"
  t.datetime "start_time"
  ... etc.
end

create_table "addresses" do |t|
  t.string   "first_line"
  ...etc.
end
```

EDIT
Updated :has_one -> :belongs_to on Residents and Parties as correctly advised by @klochner.

Comment: I think you want belongs_to in the Resident and Party classes (and address_id would be in those tables)

Comment: could you please provide an example table structure for the Resident and Address tables?

Comment: Using a has_one association means that the address will belong to only 1 resident. The association needs to be a belongs_to as per my explanation.